# Using file-loader with es6 modules and typescript in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

`webpack.config.js`:

```
resolveLoader: { 
    alias: {
        'copy': 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=./src',
    }
},
```

When I was using javascript, this worked:

`entry.js`:

```
 var index = require("copy!../src/index.html");
```

But I have moved to typescript, using (ts-loader), so I slightly modified what I was doing in `entry.ts`:

```
import * as index from 'copy!index.html';
```

but this now gives me an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/entry.ts
(3,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'copy!../src/index.html'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot find module 'copy!../src/index.html'.

External modules not written in TypeScript must be declared.

## Quick Fix

just use the `require` function as defined here : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#code-splitting-and-loading-other-resources

Code:

```
declare var require: {
  <T>(path: string): T;
  (paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
  ensure: (
    paths: string[],
    callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void
  ) => void;
};
```

Comment: @AndyJ fixed link and added content from link as well

Answer (score 12):

With TypeScript 2 you can have wildcard module declarations:

```
declare module "*!text" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
// Some do it the other way around.
declare module "json!*" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Now you can import things that match "*!text" or "json!*".

```
import fileContent from "./xyz.txt!text";
import data from "json!http://example.com/data.json";
console.log(data, fileContent);
```

Comment: And where do I place these wildcard module declarations?

Comment: placing it in a file named index.d.ts works for me. Not sure if module declarations can be placed to other locations too.

Comment: When I use this technique, I am unable to get compile-time errors for missing files. For example I can do `import totallyFake from './totally/fake/file.txt';`, and my React app with TS will compile no problem, despite the fact that that file doesn't exist. Which means I'm no better off than if I just plopped the file in the `/public` directory and used `<a href='/path/to/file.txt'></a>`. Anyone know of a way to get these imports working in a way that makes TS happy, and also ensures that the file exists?

Answer (score 8):

[alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794399/310988) is a great one, and is very flexible.

I came across [an alternative](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/12) which is more specific to a file type, so it's less flexible, but doesn't require prefixes/suffixes.

1. Create a file with `declare module '*.png'`
2. Import with `import * as logo from "./ss-logo-transparent.png";`

Comment: When I use this technique, I am unable to get compile-time errors for missing files. For example I can do import totallyFake from './totally/fake/file.txt';, and my React app with TS will compile no problem, despite the fact that that file doesn't exist. Which means I'm no better off than if I just plopped the file in the /public directory and used <a href='/path/to/file.txt'></a>. Anyone know of a way to get these imports working in a way that makes TS happy, and also ensures that the file exists?