# Webpack: import TypeScript module both "normally" and as raw string

Tags: typescript, import, webpack, ts-loader, raw-loader

Using webpack `^v2.2.1`, I would like to import a TypeScript module as text, in addition to importing the same module "normally".

I've figured that I probably should use the [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/). But it isn't working out.

Some example code:

```
import DemoComponent from './demo'
import demoCode from 'raw-loader!./demo'
```

TypeScript is screaming at me that something like

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'raw-loader!./demo'.
```

I'm using [ts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader).

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const { resolve } = require('path')
const fail = require('webpack-fail-plugin')

const config = {
  entry: './docs/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'docs-build')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    fail
  ]
}

module.exports = config
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915930/using-file-loader-with-es6-modules-and-typescript-in-webpack

Answer (score 22):

In case anyone is searching for a solution to this answer. Using `import` is the best option - it will be typed and allow optimizations from module bundlers like Rollup and Webpack 3+ when outputting `import` vs `require`:

You need to create a `raw-loader.d.ts` and make sure it is included by your `tsconfig.json`file. Enter the following contents:

```js
declare module '!!raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string
  export = contents
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["raw-loader.d.ts", "node"]
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it mean if we get "Cannot find type definition file for raw-loader.d.ts" even though that file is present in the same folder?

Comment: @Andy, just don't add anything extra into the `tsconfig.json`. Just the file `.d.ts` is anough.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the following is working:

```
import DemoComponent from './demo'
const demoCode = require('!!raw-loader!./demo')
```

But I'm not sure how correct this is. I would love to find some documentation about the order and mechanism of loaders.

Also, I would prefer to be consistent, by using `import` statements, instead. But TypeScript is complaining about it if I do a straight conversion:

```
import DemoComponent from './demo'
import demoCode from '!!raw-loader!./demo'
```

The error is a simple

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '!!raw-loader!./demo'.
```

Comment: I happen to be enjoying the benefit of `require`'s runtime nature, in this case, so I'm going to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a full explanation about it here:
https://yonatankra.com/how-to-solve-ts2307-cannot-find-module-when-using-inline-webpack-loaders-with-typescript/

In summary:

You can import using this syntax: `import template from 'raw-loader!./component.template.html';`

For this to work for any type of file you'd need to:

1. Setup a module declaration:
   `raw-loader.d.ts`

```
declare module '!!raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string
  export default contents
}
```

2. Use it in your `tsConfig.json` and add the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` property to allow modules without a default export to be imported this way:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["raw-loader.d.ts", "node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

In the article I also explain how to make this work if (for some truly bizarre reason) you'd like to use `template.default`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`raw-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) appears to be **deprecated with Webpack 5**, they recommend [configuring the built-in `asset/source`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#replacing-inline-loader-syntax) instead. The following is what worked for me:

in webpack config:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      resourceQuery: /raw/,
      type: 'asset/source'
    }
  ]
}
```

raw-asset-source.d.ts

```
declare module '*?raw' {
  const rawFileContent: string
  export default rawFileContent
}
```

then you can do imports like

```js
import demoCode from './demo?raw'
```

and `demoCode` should be a string containing the contents of the file

Answer (score 0):

For your error:

`raw-loader.d.ts`:

```
declare module '!!raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string
  export default contents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing the "!!" from @Nicolas's answer works

```
declare module 'raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string
  export default contents
}
```

I don't have the time to dive in but just in case someone needs it. I'm using typescript@4.9.5 & next@13.4.7